# How to cross join multiple Lists in Java?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Cross Join concept is the same as database cross join. I have multiple lists lets say 3 to start with and I have to join the lists as below:

```
List<E> l1: {a, b},
List<E> l2: {c, d},
List<E> l3: {e, f},
```

Cross join should produce:

```
List<E> l4 = {a, c, f},
List<E> l5 = {a, c, e},
List<E> l6 = {a, d, f},
List<E> l7 = {a, d, e},
List<E> l8 = {b, c, f},
List<E> l9 = {b, c, e},
List<E> l10 = {b, d, f},
List<E> l11= {b, d, e};
```

3 Lists with 3 elements each will give 27 new lists. And number of elements in each list is same, always.

Now one possible solution is to iterate with three for loops and then add to 3 new lists.
Is there any other possible way to achieve this so that complexity is lower?

Thanks

Comment: Will the input lists always be the same size?

Comment: actually that part is also an issue. had it be the same, I would have looped without an issue? This makes the situation complex.

Comment: looks like a permutation use case

Comment: If I understood correctly, it seems like this is just the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product. In any case, similar questions have already been asked and answered. See, for example,  http://stackoverflow.com/a/21458296/3182664

Answer (score 1):

This code will work for any `List<List<T>>` parameter.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
public class X {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<String>> param = new ArrayList<List<String>>() {{
            add(Arrays.asList("A", "B"));
            add(Arrays.asList("C", "D"));
            add(Arrays.asList("E", "F"));
        }};
        for (List<String> l : getCross(param)) {
            System.out.println(l);
        }
    }

    public static <T> List<List<T>> getCross(List<List<T>> values) {
        List<List<T>> accumulator = new ArrayList<List<T>>();
        if (values.size() != 0) {
            List<T> comb = new ArrayList<T>();
            comb.addAll(Collections.<T>nCopies(values.size(), null));
            getCross(accumulator, 0, comb, values);
        }
        return accumulator;
    }

    private static <T> void getCross(List<List<T>> accumulator, int idx, List<T> combination, List<List<T>> param) {
        if (idx == combination.size()) {
            accumulator.add(new ArrayList<T>(combination));
        } else {
            for(T t : param.get(idx)) {
                combination.set(idx, t);
                getCross(accumulator, idx + 1, combination, param);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The way I make the parameter list might be confusing. It's basically list of lists of strings. It works for any number of lists even if lists have different number of element. The only limitation is stack space because it's a recursive function. Anything below 1000 lists will work though.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will work for any kind of metric.

```
static void joinList()
    {
        List l11 = new ArrayList();

        List l22 = new ArrayList();
        List l33 = new ArrayList();

        l11.add("a");
        l11.add("b");

        l22.add("c");
        l22.add("d");

        l33.add("e");
        l33.add("f");    

        List<List> crosslist = new ArrayList<List>();
        for(int i =0;i<l11.size();i++)
        {
            for(int j=0 ; j<l22.size();j++)
            {
                for(int k =0; k<l33.size();k++)
                {

                    List list = new ArrayList();
                    list.add(l11.get(i));
                    list.add(l22.get(j));
                    list.add(l33.get(k));

                    crosslist.add(list);

                }
            }
        }   
    }
```

Comment: The question stated *"I have multiple lists lets say 3 to start with"* - your example can not be generalized to an arbitrary number of lists...

Answer (score 0):

try my solution,

you can use here as much as you need lists.

```
public class Main{
    private void run() {
        List<String> l11 = new ArrayList<String>(){{add("a");add("b");}};
        List<String> l22 = new ArrayList<String>(){{add("c");add("d");}};
        List<String> l33 = new ArrayList<String>(){{add("e");add("f");}};

        crossJoin(l11, l22, l33);
    }

    public void crossJoin(List<String> ... lists) {
        for (List<String> list : lists) {
            mixList(list, lists);
        }
    }

    private void mixList(List<String> list, List<String>[] lists) {
        for (List<String> listSrt : lists) {
            if (listSrt == list) continue;
            for (String baseString : list) {
                System.out.print(baseString + " ");
                for (String outerStr : listSrt ) {
                    System.out.print(outerStr + " ");
                }
                System.out.println(" ");
            }
        }

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.run();
    }
}
```